# Encryption/Decryption not Returning Original Length of Data

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rijndael

I don't understand why the code below is failing.

```
public string Encrypt(System.Byte value)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(BitConverter.GetBytes(value)));
}

public bool Decrypt(string encryptedValue, out System.Byte value)
{
    byte[] data = Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedValue));
    if (data.Length != sizeof(System.Byte))  // <===== THIS IS TRUE!!!
    {
        value = default(System.Byte);
        return false;
    }
    value = data[0];
    return true;
}
```

Specifically, the `byte` array returned from `Decrypt(byte[], out byte)` is 2 bytes long, instead of the expected 1 byte in length.

Note that the second byte appears to always be zero and the first byte has the correct value. So I can make the code work by just taking the first byte. But does anyone know why I'm getting the extra byte. I'm guessing it may be related to `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Below are my underlying `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods.

```
public virtual byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
{
    using (Rijndael algorithm = Rijndael.Create())
    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(Key.KeyString, Key.KeyBytes))
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (Stream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public virtual byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
{
    using (Rijndael algorithm = Rijndael.Create())
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(Key.KeyString, Key.KeyBytes))
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (Stream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would `data.Length == sizeof(byte)`? sizeof is probably returning 1 all the time...

Comment: For this method, it needs to always return 1 because that is the size of the data being decrypted (byte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BitConverter.GetBytes` method doesn't provide an overload that takes a `byte`. My guess is that it's promoting it to a (2 byte) `ushort` and then encrypting that, hence the 2 byte result when you decrypt.

Comment: Well done. That's exactly what was happening. I completely missed that. Thanks!